# Calendar provider changed event not firing at time

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, asus

I have an application since much time ago which listens to events when calendar events change. I did it adding this to manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.name.CatchChangesReceiver"
    android:priority="1000" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then creating a simple class which extends broadcast receiver:

```
public class CatchChangesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // add processing here with some query to content provider
        // in my project I use this selection for getting events:
        final String SELECTION = CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + "="
        + calendarId + " AND " + "("
        + CalendarContract.Events.DIRTY + "=" + 1 + " OR "
        + CalendarContract.Events.DELETED + "=" + 1 + ")" + " AND "
        + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " > "
        + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

This had always worked for me, as application exists since years ago. I used to have Samsung devices, where calendar was an application called S Planner.
Now I have an Asus Zenfone Max. It has Google Calendar installed. But now this listener doesn't work properly. Since I add a new event until the listener fires up, there is a great delay. Even I think that when I create a calendar event, the listener doesn't launch unless I close and open calendar app several times.
The issue is that the listener is launched at some moment, but not when it should be, instead, there is a big delay since I create the calendar event until the listener is called. Why is there such a delay?

Comment: I added {android:exported="true"} to the manifest, it works!